# Porting Motif, From AIX to RHEL 6.1

Tags: makefile, redhat, aix, porting, motif

This is my question here, but it seemed a better place then on motifzone -- their last post was over a year ago.

I am tasked with porting a ~150k line application from AIX 5.3L to RHEL 6.1
I am running Motif 2.1 on AIX, and OpenMotif 2.1.32(same build?) on Redhat.

I have managed to get the makefile going, and am able to build/link just fine.
When I try to run it, I get the errors:

```
Warning: Cannot find callback list in XTAddCallback 
Error: DialogShell widget supports only one RectObj child.
```

I realize that these immediately point to wrong parameters in the calls, but I am unable to figure out where things might be going wrong. Nothing has been changed in any motif code during the port, so I can assume that this is a redhat or motif version problem.

Can anyone here help me out on what this might be?

Comment: `XtAddCallback` is an [`Xt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Toolkit_Intrinsics) function. Were you running the same version of X11 on AIX and RHEL6?

Comment: Well, I suppose there would be another question. On the AIX box, I have a /usr/X11R6 folder with all the goodies (lib, bin, include). There is no such folder on the redhat box. Googling around, it seems that that folder no linger exists, and that the functions are lumped into /usr/bin. Is that correct? Or is there a package will install that will put all the X11R6 stuff in the correct folder?

Comment: You probably want to install something like xorg-x11-devel, or whatever x11 development package is current these days.

Comment: Checked installed packages, I have xorg-x11-proto-devel package installed. On the redhat page:
xorg-x11-devel xorg-x11 X Window System application development package 6.8.2 Obsoleted by xorg-x11-proto-devel 

Seems this proto package replaced the standard one.

Comment: Did that resolve your problem? Good luck.

Comment: No...the xorg-x11-proto-devel package was already installed. So nothing changed.

Comment: If your application was compiled & linked successfully, most probably all the necessary headers & libraries are already available. I recall run-time problems if an application were linked against `-lXt -lXm` instead of `-lXm -lXt` (order matters). Additionally, have you tried to compile and link using _Motif 2.3_? 2.1 is outdated, and 2.3 has a number of bug fixes (open-source _Motif_ on Linux may contain more bugs than the same commercial version on AIX/Solaris/HP-UX).